# Incorrect icon alignment with canvaskit renderer web even after using no icon tree shaking

Tags: flutter, alignment, rendering, tree-shaking

i have written this code for custom button with suffix or prefix icon but after deployment the alignment is not coming correct for web view.

```dart
return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: widget.contentPadding,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            if (widget.prefixIcon != null) ...[
              Icon(
                widget.prefixIcon,
                size: widget.type == ButtonType.link ? 20 : widget.iconSize,
                color: widget.type == ButtonType.primary
                    ? DigitButtonConstants.defaultTextColor
                    : (widget.isDisabled
                    ? DigitButtonConstants.defaultDisabledColor
                    : DigitButtonConstants.defaultPrimaryColor),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: widget.type == ButtonType.link  ? kPadding/2:kPadding),
            ],
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                truncatedLabel,
                style: widget.type == ButtonType.link
                    ? DigitTheme.instance.mobileTheme.textTheme.bodyLarge
                    ?.copyWith(
                  height: 1.172,
                  color: widget.isDisabled
                      ? DigitButtonConstants.defaultDisabledColor
                      : DigitButtonConstants.defaultPrimaryColor,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  decorationColor: widget.isDisabled

                      ? DigitButtonConstants.defaultDisabledColor
                      : DigitButtonConstants.defaultPrimaryColor,)
                    : DigitTheme.instance.mobileTheme.textTheme.labelLarge
                    ?.copyWith(
                  height: 1.5,
                  color: widget.type == ButtonType.primary
                      ? DigitButtonConstants.defaultTextColor
                      : (widget.isDisabled
                      ? DigitButtonConstants.defaultDisabledColor
                      : DigitButtonConstants.defaultPrimaryColor),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (widget.suffixIcon != null) ...[
              SizedBox(width: widget.type == ButtonType.link  ? kPadding/2:kPadding),
              Icon(
                widget.suffixIcon,
                size: widget.type == ButtonType.link ? 20 : widget.iconSize,
                color: widget.type == ButtonType.primary
                    ? DigitButtonConstants.defaultTextColor
                    : (widget.isDisabled
                    ? DigitButtonConstants.defaultDisabledColor
                    : DigitButtonConstants.defaultPrimaryColor),
              ),
            ],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

i was expecting something like this

[image]

but after deployment it is looking like this

[image]

and this is working fine is android devide only for web i am getting this issue.